# Google Chrome Removal and Installation

Tags: powershell, google-chrome, intune

I am working on a script to uninstall Google Chrome and Reinstall it via Intune (Microsoft Endpoint Manager). Recently, we've had so many problems getting Chrome updated as it keeps producing errors.

[image: error1]

[image: error2]

According to the offical [Google Chrome update error page](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/111996?hl=en) the error code is due to "An error occurred while checking for updates: Download failed." The suggested fix does not do anything as well as anything else found on the internet. The only thing that seems to fix it is force uninstalling Chrome and deleting every trace of the app in the registry. To do I've created a script so far in my testing the script works at uninstalling Chrome but doesn't work in deleting any registry keys as well as won't reinstall Chrome.

My script:

```
Start-Transcript "C:\Intune Packages\Google Chrome\Installer\log.txt"

Write-host "Closing all instances of Google Chrome..."
cmd /c taskkill /IM Chrome.exe /F

#Identify version and GUID of Google Chrome
Write-host "Identifying Google Chrome location..."
$AppInfo = Get-WmiObject Win32_Product -Filter "Name Like 'Google Chrome'"
$ChromeVer = $AppInfo.Version
$GUID = $AppInfo.IdentifyingNumber
Write-host "Google Chrome is installed as version:" $ChromeVer
Write-host "Google Chrome has GUID of:" $GUID


#Uninstall using MSIEXEC
Write-host "Attempting uninstall using MSIEXEC..."
& ${env:WINDIR}\System32\msiexec /x $GUID /Quiet /Passive /NoRestart


#Uninstall using Setup.exe uninstaller
Write-host "Attempting uninstall using Setup.exe uninstaller..."
If(Test-Path -Path C:\Progra~1\Google\Chrome\Application\$ChromeVer\Installer\){
    Write-host "Google Chrome is installed as 64-bit program..."
    & "C:\Program Filses\Google\Chrome\Application\$ChromeVer\Installer\setup.exe" --uninstall --multi-install --chrome --system-level --force-uninstall
}
If(Test-Path -Path C:\Progra~2\Google\Chrome\Application\$ChromeVer\Installer\){
    Write-host "Google Chrome is installed as 32-bit program..."
    & "C:\Program Filses (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\$ChromeVer\Installer\setup.exe" --uninstall --multi-install --chrome --system-level --force-uninstall
}


#Uninstall using WMIC
Write-host "Attempting uninstall using WMIC..."
wmic product where "name like 'Google Chrome'" call uninstall /nointeractive


#Look for Google Chrome in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Products\
Write-host "Deleting Google Chrome folder from HKLM:\Software\Classes\Installer\Products\"
$RegPath = "HKLM:\Software\Classes\Installer\Products\"

$ChromeRegKey = Get-ChildItem -Path $RegPath | Get-ItemProperty | Where-Object {$_.ProductName -match "Google Chrome"}
    
Write-Host "Product name found:" $ChromeRegKey.ProductName
Write-Host "Folder name found:" $ChromeRegKey.PSChildName

If(!$ChromeRegKey.PSChildName){
    Write-Host "Google Chrome not found in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Products\"
}
If($ChromeRegKey.PSChildName){
    $ChromeDirToDelete = "HKLM:\Software\Classes\Installer\Products\" + $ChromeRegKey.PSChildName
    Write-Host "Google Chrome directory to delete:" $ChromeDirToDelete
    Remove-Item -Path $ChromeDirToDelete -Force -Recurse
}

Remove-Item -Path "HKCR:\AppID\{708860E0-F641-4611-8895-7D867DD3675B}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKCR:\GoogleUpdate.PolicyStatus" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKCR:\GoogleUpdate.PolicyStatus.1.0" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKCR:\Interface\{1B9063E4-3882-485E-8797-F28A0240782F}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKCR:\Interface\{6DFFE7FE-3153-4AF1-95D8-F8FCCA97E56B}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKCR:\Interface\{DDD4B5D4-FD54-497C-8789-0830F29A60EE}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKCR:\Interface\{FCE48F77-C677-4012-8A1A-54D2E2BC07BD}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKCR:\WOW6432Node\CLSID\{9F3F5F5D-721A-4B19-9B5D-69F664C1A591}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKCR:\WOW6432Node\Interface\{1B9063E4-3882-485E-8797-F28A0240782F}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKCR:\WOW6432Node\Interface\{6DFFE7FE-3153-4AF1-95D8-F8FCCA97E56B}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKCR:\WOW6432Node\Interface\{79E0C401-B7BC-4DE5-8104-71350F3A9B67}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKCR:\WOW6432Node\Interface\{DDD4B5D4-FD54-497C-8789-0830F29A60EE}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKCR:\WOW6432Node\Interface\{FCE48F77-C677-4012-8A1A-54D2E2BC07BD}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\Software\Classes\.htm\OpenWithProgids\ChromeHTML" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\Software\Classes\.html\OpenWithProgids\ChromeHTML" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\Software\Classes\.shtm\OpenWithProgids\ChromeHTML" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\Software\Classes\.webp\OpenWithProgids\ChromeHTML" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\.webp\ShellEx\{BB2E617C-0920-11d1-9A0B-00C04FC2D6C1}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\Software\Classes\.xht\OpenWithProgids\ChromeHTML" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\Software\Classes\.xhtml\OpenWithProgids\ChromeHTML" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\Software\Classes\AppID\{4EB61BAC-A3B6-9581-655041EF4D69}\" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\AppID\{9465B4B4-5216-4042-9A2C-754D3BCDC410}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\AppID\GoogleUpdate.exe" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\ChromeHTML" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\Software\Classes\Clients\StartMenuInternet\Google Chrome" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{9D6AA569-9F30-41AD-885A-346685C74928}\InprocServer32HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\GoogleUpdate.CoCreateAsync" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\GoogleUpdate.CoCreateAsync.1.0" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\GoogleUpdate.CoreClass" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\GoogleUpdate.CoreClass.1" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\GoogleUpdate.CredentialDialogMachine" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\GoogleUpdate.CredentialDialogMachine.1.0" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\GoogleUpdate.OnDemandCOMClassMachine" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\GoogleUpdate.OnDemandCOMClassMachine.1.0" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\GoogleUpdate.OnDemandCOMClassMachineFallback" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\GoogleUpdate.OnDemandCOMClassMachineFallback.1.0" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\GoogleUpdate.OnDemandCOMClassSvc" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\GoogleUpdate.OnDemandCOMClassSvc.1.0" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\GoogleUpdate.ProcessLauncher" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\GoogleUpdate.ProcessLauncher.1.0" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\GoogleUpdate.Update3COMClassService" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\GoogleUpdate.Update3COMClassService.1.0" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\GoogleUpdate.Update3WebMachine" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\GoogleUpdate.Update3WebMachine.1.0" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\GoogleUpdate.Update3WebMachineFallback" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\GoogleUpdate.Update3WebMachineFallback.1.0" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\GoogleUpdate.Update3WebSvc" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\GoogleUpdate.Update3WebSvc.1.0" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{084D78A8-B084-4E14-A629-A2C419B0E3D9}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{0CD01D1E-4A1C-489D-93B9-9B6672877C57}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{128C2DA6-2BC0-44C0-B3F6-4EC22E647964}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{18D0F672-18B4-48E6-AD36-6E6BF01DBBC4}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{19692F10-ADD2-4EFF-BE54-E61C62E40D13}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{1C642CED-CA3B-4013-A9DF-CA6CE5FF6503}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{247954F9-9EDC-4E68-8CC3-150C2B89EADF}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{2D363682-561D-4C3A-81C6-F2F82107562A}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{2E629606-312A-482F-9B12-2C4ABF6F0B6D}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{31AC3F11-E5EA-4A85-8A3D-8E095A39C27B}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{3D05F64F-71E3-48A5-BF6B-83315BC8AE1F}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{494B20CF-282E-4BDD-9F5D-B70CB09D351E}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{49D7563B-2DDB-4831-88C8-768A53833837}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{4DE778FE-F195-4EE3-9DAB-FE446C239221}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{4E223325-C16B-4EEB-AEDC-19AA99A237FA}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{5B25A8DC-1780-4178-A629-6BE8B8DEFAA2}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{6DB17455-4E85-46E7-9D23-E555E4B005AF}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{76F7B787-A67C-4C73-82C7-31F5E3AABC5C}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{79E0C401-B7BC-4DE5-8104-71350F3A9B67}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{8476CE12-AE1F-4198-805C-BA0F9B783F57}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{909489C2-85A6-4322-AA56-D25278649D67}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{B3A47570-0A85-4AEA-8270-529D47899603}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{BCDCB538-01C0-46D1-A6A7-52F4D021C272}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{D106AB5F-A70E-400E-A21B-96208C1D8DBB}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{DAB1D343-1B2A-47F9-B445-93DC50704BFE}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{DCAB8386-4F03-4DBD-A366-D90BC9F68DE6}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{DD42475D-6D46-496A-924E-BD5630B4CBBA}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{FE908CDD-22BB-472A-9870-1A0390E42F36}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{25461599-633D-42B1-84FB-7CD68D026E53}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{4EB61BAC-A3B6-4760-9581-655041EF4D69}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{534F5323-3569-4F42-919D-1E1CF93E5BF6}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{598FE0E5-E02D-465D-9A9D-37974A28FD42}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{6F8BD55B-E83D-4A47-85BE-81FFA8057A69}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{7DE94008-8AFD-4C70-9728-C6FBFFF6A73E}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{8A1D4361-2C08-4700-A351-3EAA9CBFF5E4}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{9465B4B4-5216-4042-9A2C-754D3BCDC410}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{9B2340A0-4068-43D6-B404-32E27217859D}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{9D6AA569-9F30-41AD-885A-346685C74928}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{ABC01078-F197-4B0B-ADBC-CFE684B39C82}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{B3D28DBD-0DFA-40E4-8071-520767BADC7E}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{E225E692-4B47-4777-9BED-4FD7FE257F0E}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{084D78A8-B084-4E14-A629-A2C419B0E3D9}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{0CD01D1E-4A1C-489D-93B9-9B6672877C57}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{128C2DA6-2BC0-44C0-B3F6-4EC22E647964}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{18D0F672-18B4-48E6-AD36-6E6BF01DBBC4}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{19692F10-ADD2-4EFF-BE54-E61C62E40D13}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{1C642CED-CA3B-4013-A9DF-CA6CE5FF6503}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{247954F9-9EDC-4E68-8CC3-150C2B89EADF}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{2D363682-561D-4C3A-81C6-F2F82107562A}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{2E629606-312A-482F-9B12-2C4ABF6F0B6D}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{31AC3F11-E5EA-4A85-8A3D-8E095A39C27B}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{3D05F64F-71E3-48A5-BF6B-83315BC8AE1F}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{494B20CF-282E-4BDD-9F5D-B70CB09D351E}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{49D7563B-2DDB-4831-88C8-768A53833837}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{4DE778FE-F195-4EE3-9DAB-FE446C239221}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{4E223325-C16B-4EEB-AEDC-19AA99A237FA}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{5B25A8DC-1780-4178-A629-6BE8B8DEFAA2}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{6DB17455-4E85-46E7-9D23-E555E4B005AF}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{76F7B787-A67C-4C73-82C7-31F5E3AABC5C}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{8476CE12-AE1F-4198-805C-BA0F9B783F57}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{909489C2-85A6-4322-AA56-D25278649D67}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{B3A47570-0A85-4AEA-8270-529D47899603}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{BCDCB538-01C0-46D1-A6A7-52F4D021C272}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{D106AB5F-A70E-400E-A21B-96208C1D8DBB}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{DAB1D343-1B2A-47F9-B445-93DC50704BFE}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{DCAB8386-4F03-4DBD-A366-D90BC9F68DE6}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{DD42475D-6D46-496A-924E-BD5630B4CBBA}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{FE908CDD-22BB-472A-9870-1A0390E42F36}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet\Google Chrome" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\Software\Google" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components\{8A69D345-D564-463c-AFF1-A69D9E530F96}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ActiveSync\WebAuth\Gmail" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\EnterpriseDesktopAppManagement\S-0-0-00-0000000000-0000000000-000000000-000\MSI\{A49A0C51-914A-36A0-B6C2-D34A4BF8710A}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\IdentityCRL\ThrottleCache" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MediaPlayer\ShimInclusionList\chrome.exe" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\GoogleUpdate.exe" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule\TaskCache\Tasks\{18635495-7837-4E21-AAE0-78E9D85A7805}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule\TaskCache\Tasks\{21C02D29-38ED-478E-9D06-6C2F4C21CF75}" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule\TaskCache\Tree\GoogleUpdateTaskMachineCore" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule\TaskCache\Tree\GoogleUpdateTaskMachineUA" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\chrome.exe" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CapabilityAccessManager\ConsentStore\microphone\NonPackaged\C:#Program Files (x86)#Google#Chrome#Application#chrome.exe" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\UFH\ARP" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\Software\Micrsoft\IntuneManagementExtension\Inventories\0000900334a13d6d54fa42b947e821487ea200000904\Name - Google Chrome" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\RegisteredApplications\Google Chrome - Software\Clients\StartMenuInternet\Google Chrome\Capabilties" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\Software\WOW6432Node\Clients\StartMenuInternet\Google Chrome" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Google" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\Software\WOW6432Node\RegsiteredApplications\Google Chrome - Software\Clients\StartMenuInternet\Google" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\gupdate" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\gupdatem" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\Setup\FirstBoot\Services\GoogleChromeElevationService" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\Setup\FirstBoot\Services\gupdate" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\Setup\FirstBoot\Services\gupdatem" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKU:\S-1-5-19\SOFTWARE\Google" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue
Remove-Item -Path "HKU:\S-1-5-20\SOFTWARE\Google" -recurse -force #-erroraction silentlycontinue


Remove-Item -Path "C:\Program Filses\Google\Chrome\" -Force -Recurse
Remove-Item -Path "C:\Program Filses (x86)\Google\Chrome\" -Force -Recurse

Write-host "Uninstall operations have all completed." -fore green

start-process msiexec.exe -argumentlist "/i .\GoogleChromeStandaloneEnterprise64.msi /Quiet /Passive /NoRestart"

Stop-Transcript
```

I've tested the script without uploading through Intune and it also doesn't work to remove the registry keys or reinstall Chrome.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [uninstall google chrome using powershell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69666628/uninstall-google-chrome-using-powershell-script)

Comment: Additionally, stop using the EXE installer for corporate management of Google Chrome. My linked answer solves removing this in an automated fashion but relies on undocumented behavior. Use the [MSI version](https://chromeenterprise.google/browser/download/#windows-tab) for managing Chrome installations in an enterprise instead, which gives you the benefit of standard Windows software inventory management.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest we are not using the EXE am using the MSI. Now I cannot speak to what was previously installed for others, but I know I had mine installed with the MSI and I ran into the same error a few months later. I will check out your link.

Comment: Interesting, to my knowledge the enterprise MSI installation will give Chrome a GUID as the software inventory key, and the EXE gives it a text-based name as shown in your screenshot. That is how it is on my work laptop and Chrome is deployed with the MSI also.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest I think you are thinking of the GUILD from the uninstall path in the registry [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{C0A46265-716E-345D-BB59-72B42D15135B}] the software still gets listed by name under KHLM:\Software\
I tested your script from your other post and it works as mine does to uninstall the software registry keys still remain and it doesn't provide an option to reinstall.

Comment: My mistake, you're right, I misread that reg path. I've removed the dupe flag, but note that you might find a better audience for this question on Super User since it involves purging a computer of the Google Chrome software.

Comment: Looking at your errors and script again, only the `HKCU:` and `HKLM:` hives are loaded as PSDrives by default. If I have time later I can look at this more and write up a proper answer but for now I'll point you to this link on making other registry hives available as PSDrives: https://lazyadmin.nl/powershell/new-psdrive/. Search for the section titled **Mapping Registry keys with New-PSDrive**. That however does not explain why presumably available paths under HKLM and HKCU are failing to resolve.

Comment: A copy of the script I've made available at https://pastebin.com/ppJ7Gpy6